# Bootstrap responsive design problem: How to force images to stay at the bottom of a div?

Tags: html, css, responsive, bootstrap-5

I am using the product example of Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/product/) on my website https://trimlog.de/. Everything is working fine except that on my iPad or if I zoom in on my computer the images on the website move. Here you can see what it looks like: [image: Here you can see what it looks like]

Compared to what it looks like on my computer without zooming in: [image: Compared to what it looks like on my computer without zooming in]

Does anyone have an idea how I can force the images to stay at the bottom?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="d-md-flex flex-md-equal w-100 my-md-3 ps-md-3">
        <div class="bg-dark me-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center text-white overflow-hidden" id="boats">
            <div class="my-3 py-3">
                <h2 class="display-5"><i class="fas fa-anchor"></i> Add your boat</h2>
                <p class="lead">We offer presets for many boats and are working on adding your boat to the Trimlog app.
                    In relation to your boat, the boat specific data will be stored.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-light shadow-sm mx-auto" id="boats-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-secondary me-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center text-white overflow-hidden" id="trims">
            <div class="my-3 p-3">
                <h2 class="display-5"><i class="fas fa-wrench"></i> Record trims</h2>
                <p class="lead">During the training you try many different trims in different weather conditions at
                    different locations. Record this data while you're on the water so you'll never forget it.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-dark shadow-sm mx-auto" id="trims-bg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-md-flex flex-md-equal w-100 my-md-3 ps-md-3">
        <div class="bg-warning me-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center text-dark overflow-hidden" id="analytics">
            <div class="my-3 p-3">
                <h2 class="display-5"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i> Analyse your trims</h2>
                <p class="lead">If you are about to race, you are probably questioning which trim is the right one. You
                    can look at analysis graphs to see what your experience has shown.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-dark shadow-sm mx-auto" id="analytics-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-primary me-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center text-white overflow-hidden"
             id="calculations">
            <div class="my-3 py-3">
                <h2 class="display-5"><i class="fas fa-calculator"></i> Get an automatically calculated trim</h2>
                <p class="lead">If you are in a hurry, or unsure about the perfect trim even with the informative
                    graphs, the Trimlog app can calculate a trim that fits the location and weather conditions.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-light shadow-sm mx-auto" id="calculations-bg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the styling:

```
#boats-bg {
    background-image: url("../assets/images/sailing/DSC06987.JPG");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 80%;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;
}

#trims-bg {
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: url("../assets/images/sailing/DSC06851.JPG");
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 80%;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;
}

#analytics-bg {
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: url("../assets/images/sailing/DSC06576.JPG");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 80%;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;
}

#calculations-bg {
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: url("../assets/images/sailing/DSC06957.JPG");
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 80%;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap example seemingly has the same problem.

From testing on your site in the inspector I think you could approach this problem by making a class for each of your card divs (The divs with ids: boats, trims, etc...) and a class for the picture inside each card div.

Lets's say this card class is called `custom-card` and the class for the picture inside the card is called `custom-card-image`, then you could do something like this:

```
div.custom-card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

div.custom-card-image {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

This would make it so each `custom-card-image` is always on the bottom of its respective `custom-card` parent.

---

`display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` make it so the items in the card are positioned underneath each other.

`flex-grow` specifies how much of the remaining space in the flex container should be assigned to the item ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow#description)). Because we give it `1` it takes up all the remaining space.

Comment: That already looks good, but the problem now is that the text disappears behind the images: https://imgur.com/a/7agdDn8 I pushed the changes to https://www.trimlog.de/ Do you have an idea what I did wrong or what I have to add?

Comment: Yeah that was a problem with my `position: absolute` approach. I've edited my question with an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, a combination of your answer and kantbtrue's worked best for me. I took `mt-auto` for the image from the other answer and other than that took the styling from your answer. Without the `mt-auto` there is the same problem as before. Here is my HTML and styling: https://pastebin.com/R1cBxUAb

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

cards have equal height irrespective of their content that makes the image's uneven position in a card.

[image]

## Solution

Enable flexbox context to all the card children and make the image `margin-top` to `auto` to stick it at the bottom.

1. Add two classes `d-flex` and `flex-wrap` to card
2. `mt-auto` class to the image

```
<div class="d-md-flex flex-md-equal w-100 my-md-3 ps-md-3">
    <div class="bg-dark me-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center text-white overflow-hidden d-flex flex-wrap" id="boats">
        <div class="my-3 py-3">
            <h2 class="display-5"><i class="fas fa-anchor"></i> Add your boat</h2>
            <p class="lead">We offer presets for many boats and are working on adding your boat to the Trimlog app.
                In relation to your boat, the boat specific data will be stored.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-light shadow-sm mx-auto mt-auto" id="boats-bg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-secondary me-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center text-white overflow-hidden d-flex flex-wrap" id="trims">
        <div class="my-3 p-3">
            <h2 class="display-5"><i class="fas fa-wrench"></i> Record trims</h2>
            <p class="lead">During the training you try many different trims in different weather conditions at
                different locations. Record this data while you're on the water so you'll never forget it.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-dark shadow-sm mx-auto mt-auto" id="trims-bg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, a combination of your answer and Bas van der Linden's worked best for me. I took `mt-auto` for the picture from your answer and other than that I took the styling from the other answer. This answer also works for itself, but a combination looked better.